# Identity Server 4 Scopes found on current principal: ""

Tags: api, implicit, identityserver4

I attempting to use Identity Server 4 to authenticate users before granting access to a API. I am using a Implicit configuration as the front end is a Ember JS app. I have been able to Login, display the consent screen and then navigate to the redirectUri. However as soon as the Bearer Token is sent to the API I get back a 403.

I was able to find in the logs right before the 403 is returned it states there are not any scopes specified for the current principle. However I have yet to find anyone else reporting the same issue so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

API LOG

```
2017-03-27 15:24:35.358 -05:00 [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:55026/incentives/api/categories application/json 
    2017-03-27 15:24:36.035 -05:00 [Information] Successfully validated the token.
    2017-03-27 15:24:36.046 -05:00 [Information] HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: "Bearer".
    2017-03-27 15:24:36.048 -05:00 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was successfully authenticated.
    2017-03-27 15:24:36.051 -05:00 [Information] Scopes found on current principal: ""
    2017-03-27 15:24:36.053 -05:00 [Warning] Scope validation failed. Return 403
    2017-03-27 15:24:36.059 -05:00 [Debug] Connection id ""0HL3L9SNQEILQ"" completed keep alive response.
    2017-03-27 15:24:36.060 -05:00 [Information] Request finished in 702.0523ms 403  

new Client
            {
                ClientName = "IncentivesClient",
                ClientId = "IncentivesClient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:4200/authorized"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:4200/unauthorized"
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:4200"
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    StandardScopes.Email,
                    StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "incentiveRecords",
                    "incentiverecordsscope",
                }
            }
```

This is the API settings

```
IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions identityServerValidationOptions = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44357",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
            AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "incentiveRecords" },
            ApiSecret = "incentiveRecordsSecret",
            ApiName = "incentiveRecords",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Both,
            AuthenticationScheme = "Bearer",
            SaveToken = true,
            ValidateScope = true,
            // TokenRetriever = _tokenRetriever,
            // required if you want to return a 403 and not a 401 for forbidden responses
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
        };
```

Comment: Show how you've defined your clients in your IdSvr, and how you are requesting a token.

Comment: @Mashton I've added the Client information. As far as requesting a token I am using ember-simple-auth and torri. Which is calling /connect/authorize at the IdSvr and getting back a id_token and a auth code. Then I am sending that auth code in the Authorization Header as the Bearer Token when attempting to make the first API call.

Comment: I realized that I should have said access token instead of auth code. The response types requested are id_token token. The token(JWT) in the response is what is being sent to the API in the Authorization Header. When the token is decoded I have noticed that the audience is set to the client and the only way I was able to get as far as I have is by setting the ApiName property in the IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions on the API to that client name. If I set the ApiName to what I feel is the correct value I get a Audience validation failure. I have a feeling this is my underlying issue.

Comment: I think you are right. You API settings should have the Audience setting of your IdSvr, not your client, and the desired scopes. Then when your API is inspecting the access token it will reject tokens that don't come from the authority it respects. Maybe add your API config to the question?

Comment: I added the API Identity Server settings. I also changed the ApiName, which is also what I have set in my APIResource, to what I think it should be but as I said when it is set as that  I get the Audience validation error.

Comment: Like I was saying I feel like the issued access token should have an audience of "incentiveRecords" but I do not know how to tell the IdSvr that the audience is something other than the client requesting it. I am able to decode the token using this site [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) and that is where I see the audience is set to the client.

Comment: I just found this and it may shed some light on my situation. [Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/279). So something has been bothering me since last week when I first got the client interacting with the IdSvr and getting back the id_token and the access token and that is that they are identical. Now that is at the point that I have access to the data after torii has done all the grunt work and called the connnect/authorize endpoint. But it has seemed like that should not be the case and now I am thinking maybe I only have the id_token and torii is at fault.

Comment: Has your `incentiveRecord` scope been defined as a `ApiResource` or an `IdentityResource`? I saw this mentioned on the IdSvr docs ... "id_token requests an identity token (only identity scopes are allowed)

token requests an access token (only resource scopes are allowed)". If none of your scopes are ApiResource scopes then your access token won't have any scopes on it.

Comment: I saw something similar to that as well. It is specified as a ApiResource and the scopes I have specified to be used in my request are a combination of identity and resource scopes which should be fine because my response types are id_token and token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that I had found for implementing your own torii provider for OATH2 had instructed to include 'id_token' and 'token' in the response params  which made sense considering they are the response type being utilized in my Implicit configuration. To add to the confusion both the id_token and token were obtaining values successfully after the promise. It did bother me that they were identical and when I decoded them the audience was set to the client instead of including the resource server. So the super simple answer was to change the 'token' response param to 'access_token'. Now I am able to obtain the correct token from the promise and move on to utilizing it within the Auth header. Hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: I finally figured this out this morning. Now that I know the answer it is kind of infuriating but at least maybe by sharing my mistake I can save others from the same week of desperation.